# How to call a service inside a python node?

Tags: ros, call-service, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to subscribe a data in a python node and for different values of subscribed values, call a predefined service from another package and make it True or False. As it is explained for  [this question](https://answers.ros.org/question/201617/how-to-call-a-service-inside-a-node/) or in [this link](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/rosservice/html/rosservice-pysrc.html#call_service), I have tried call_service function but get this error.

```
[ERROR] [1579531979.101601]: bad callback: <function callback_receive at 0x7efd5a15dd70>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 750, in _invoke_callback
cb(msg)
File "/home/ehsan/catkin_ws/src/fsr_sensor/scripts/subscriber_node.py", line 16, in callback_receive
rosservice.call_service('/joint2_controller/torque_enable',False)
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosservice/__init__.py", line 411, in call_service
rospy.init_node('rosservice', anonymous=True)
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/client.py", line 274, in init_node
raise rospy.exceptions.ROSException("rospy.init_node() has already been called with different arguments: 
"+str(_init_node_args))
ROSException: rospy.init_node() has already been called with different arguments: ('subscriber_node', 
['/home/ehsan/catkin_ws/src/fsr_sensor/scripts/subscriber_node.py'], False, None, False, False)
```

I attached my python node below. Thanks in advance.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
import time
from std_msgs.msg import Bool
from std_msgs.msg import Int32
import rosservice

def callback_receive(msg):
   if msg.data == 1:
      rosservice.call_service('/joint2_controller/torque_enable',True)
      rosservice.call_service('/joint1_controller/torque_enable',True)
   else:
      rosservice.call_service('/joint2_controller/torque_enable',False)
      rosservice.call_service('/joint1_controller/torque_enable',False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('subscriber_node')
    rospy.Subscriber("/X",Int32,callback_receive)

 rospy.spin()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342113/how-to-call-a-service-inside-a-python-node?/) by [ehsan_amp](https://answers.ros.org/users/49314/ehsan_amp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2020-01-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know rosservice.call_service doesn't work for this usage. I attached the code that I used.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
import time
from std_msgs.msg import Bool
from std_msgs.msg import Int32
from dynamixel_controllers.srv import TorqueEnable
import sys

def callback_receive(msg):
     rospy.wait_for_service('joint2_controller/torque_enable')
     rospy.wait_for_service('joint1_controller/torque_enable')
if msg.data == 1:
    joint2 = rospy.ServiceProxy('joint2_controller/torque_enable', TorqueEnable)
    joint1 = rospy.ServiceProxy('joint1_controller/torque_enable', TorqueEnable)
    joint_2=joint2(True)
    joint_1=joint1(True)
    
elif msg.data == 0:
    joint2 = rospy.ServiceProxy('joint2_controller/torque_enable', TorqueEnable)
    joint1 = rospy.ServiceProxy('joint1_controller/torque_enable', TorqueEnable)
    joint_2=joint2(False)
    joint_1=joint1(False)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('subscriber_node')
    rospy.Subscriber("/X",Int32,callback_receive)



rospy.spin()
```

---

Originally posted by [ehsan_amp](https://answers.ros.org/users/49314/ehsan_amp/) with karma: 33 on 2020-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can look at [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29) to see how to create a client to call a given service. More details are available in the [rospy service documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Services)

To call a service you need to create a service proxy. Each time you invoke that service proxy, it will send a request to the server and block until it gets a response.
In your case you'll need two different service proxies, one for `joint1_controller/torque_enable` and one for `joint2_controller/torque_enable`.

---

rosservice is a utility to interact with services from the command line e.g.:

```
rosservice call [...]
```

This should not be used inside scripts that already have ros running.

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2020-01-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ehsan_amp](https://answers.ros.org/users/49314/ehsan_amp/) on 2020-01-21**:
Thanks for your answer. I tried that and it worked! I will write it down as an answer.